# How can I update my list when I type something in search?

Tags: android, json, reactjs, react-native

```
 search = () => {
      fetch(strings.baseUri+"search_by_name", {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ 
              "name": this.state.name,
            })
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {

             this.setState({data: responseJson});     

         })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
          });    
      }
```

How can I use my search function to update my list whenever I enter something in my search box?

**This is what I'm trying in my TextInput (SearchBox).**

```
<TextInput style={styles.searchInput} 
 placeholder="Search"
 placeholderTextColor= {colors.whiteColor}
 onChangeText={ 
 name => { 
 this.setState({name}); 
 this.search(); 
}
 }
 />
```

Comment: @Pretasoc I've edited my question. Please check it. And also, can you please remove the unlike from my question so people can answer my question. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, so i cant remove that downvote.

Comment: @Pretasoc Oh I'm sorry. Also, can you please answer my query if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `responseJson` is an actual json object, you don't need to stringify it and then parse it.

You could store the responseJson in the state

```
search = () => {
      fetch(strings.baseUri+"search_by_name", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
          "name": this.state.name,
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({data: responseJson});    
     })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
      });    
  }
```

Just make sure you set the initial state in your constructor of your component

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { data: [] }
}
```

Then you should be able to access your data by using `this.state.data`

#### Updated Answer to Updated Question

The problem is that you are not realising that setState is asynchronous. That is takes time for the state to update. That means that you are setting state and then hoping that the state will have updated by the time the next function is called. Unfortunately, calling setState in your TextInput is not having the desired effect.

I would update your search function to the following

```
search = (name) => {
      fetch(strings.baseUri+"search_by_name", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
          "name": name,
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({data: responseJson, name: name});    
     })
      .catch((error) => {
          this.setState({name: name});
          console.error(error);
      });    
  }
```

Then in your`TextInput` update your function call to

```
<TextInput style={styles.searchInput} 
 placeholder="Search"
 placeholderTextColor={colors.whiteColor}
 onChangeText={ name => { 
   if (name.length > 0) {
    this.search(name); 
   } else {
    this.setState({data: [], name: ''});
   }
  }
 }
/>
```

This will reduce the number of times setState is called.

Comment: If I alert my data by `alert(this.state.data)`. I see nothing in alert box. What do I do now?

Comment: It really depends on where you are calling this.state.data. It takes time for the data to be set. Also `alert` takes a string value, this.state.data is an array so you should use `JSON.stringify` to make it work.  If you want to call it in the `.then((responseJson) => ...` call block then you should do so like this: `this.setState({ data: responseJson }, () => alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.data)));` this will call the alert after the setState has been completed. You could also console.log(this.state.data); in your render function so that you will see when it updates.

Comment: Checkout this post on setState https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0 . and this on how setState takes a callback https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Comment: Thank you. I just had to use my data in my flatlist and now I can see it.

Comment: I just updated my question. If you don't mind can you also answer this one please. :)

Comment: I would imagine that you need to set the extraData prop on the FlatList. `extraData={this.state}`. However, you are only showing snippets of code. So it makes it hard to guess what you are doing. You should ask a new question and put all relevant information into it. Firstly that makes it easy for the question to be understood as it contains the relevant information about the question, secondly I may not have the time to answer your question meaning that your edit doesn't get answered, and thirdly it makes it easier for those browsing SO for answers as they don't have to search comments

Comment: alright I'll keep that in mind next time. But for now, this is not working for me. I'm getting this error - **TaskQueue: Error with task : Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN ** I don't know why my Flatlist is not rendering again. Please help.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but the issue is I don't have the whole information for the component that you are using.  Usually that error is about passing a FlatList an object that is not an array. You probably need to do some checking before setting the responseJson to state, make sure that you are getting an array.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. I just have one last problem, if I would enter something in my TextInput the FlatList gets updated. But as soon as I would delete what I entered, the FlatList gets no data and I get the same error I mentioned previously.

Comment: You need to make sure that what you are returning from the responseJson is an array. Even if that array is an empty array. See my updated answer for a way to stop calling your `search` function if the length of the name is zero.

Comment: that works. But my FlatList doesn't get updated. I want my View to show nothing if there is no text entered in search option

Comment: Then read the docs for flatlist https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listemptycomponent

Answer (score 0):

uhm...
i'm not sure what 'body' part is for..
i mean the part 
body: JSON.stringify({"name": this.state.name})
maybe is better like
body:[{'name':bla}] ?

anyway, try with this (and write 'Accept' header as a string):
(add the body part if is so important to you)

```
const fetchConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}
fetch(strings.baseUri+"search_by_name",fetchConfig)
.then((response) => {
    //use *return* statement to return a json object to THEN part
    return JSON.parse(response)
})
.then((responseJson) => {
    let jsonObj = responseJson;//responseJson is *already* a JSON object.
    //you cannot alert a JSON data, it's will show as [object]
    //you can do console.log() or 
    //console.warn() <--- this will showed on device in yellowbox, but i'm not sure about a json data.
})
```

Comment: I just updated my question. If you don't mind can you also answer this one please. :)

Comment: try with

`onChangeText={ 
 name => { 
 this.setState({name},()=>{ this.search();  }); 
}`

*AND* remember to add "return" here

`.then((response) => {return response.json()})`

Comment: another thing, have you tried with 'GET', instead of 'POST'?